# string.replace function keep showing 'list index out of range error'

Tags: python, python-2.7

## Here is what I want

1. read large JSON file(4.8MB)
2. replace specific words to new words
3. make new file then write line to new file

Here is my code.

```
def replaceString(input,replace_list): #read one line, and in that line, replace string in replace_list[0] with string in replace_list[1]
    new_string = input
    for i in range(len(replace_list)):
        new_string = new_string.replace(replace_list[i][0], replace_list[i][1])
    return new_string

input_f = open("ko_ko.json",'r') #very long file
output_f = open("new_ko_ko.json",'w')

replace_list = [["`","'"],["&#x27"],[" !","!"],[" ?","?"]] #[ ["string to replace", "string to be replaced"] , ... ]
input_line = input_f.readlines()[0]

new_lines = replaceString(input_line,replace_list)
output_f.write(new_lines)
```

I debugged program keep showing following error

```
Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/jaegu/PycharmProjects/newJSON/makeJSON.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jaegu/PycharmProjects/newJSON/makeJSON.py", line 13, in <module>
    new_lines = replaceString(input_line,replace_list)
  File "/Users/jaegu/PycharmProjects/newJSON/makeJSON.py", line 4, in replaceString
    new_string = new_string.replace(replace_list[i][0], replace_list[i][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You have a single element list in `replace_list`: `["&#x27"]`. What did you want to replace that with?

Comment: Thank You! I noticed right after I posted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your `replace_list` elements is a list with *just one element*: `["&#x27"]`. There is no second element in that list so you get an exception. Presumably you wanted that to be `["&#27", "'"]`.

Some other remarks:

- Use tuples for your pairs; the pairs don't need to be mutable, using tuples lets you catch bugs earlier.
- Don't use `range()` when you can loop directly over your pairs:

  ```
  for old, new in replace_list:
      new_string = new_string.replace(old, new)
  ```

Comment: Also `input` is a bad name to use in practice, even in python2

Comment: @NickA: it's not that bad, the code is presumably not trying to get input from the console.

Comment: perhaps not in this case, but if not aware it could cause problems in other code

Comment: @NickA: here are so many such names. There are 144 built-ins in Python 2.7, after all.

Comment: Also true, its hard not to use any of them, `list` would be more of a problem